# Greedy Algorithm on Knockout Tournaments: Proof of Correctness

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algorithms, trees, discrete-optimization

You are given a function $\operatorname{rk}:\{1\dots 2^k\}\rightarrow \mathbb{N^+}$ representing the ranks of the players $1\dots2^k$ in a participating in a tournament. The tournament evolves in a random way, so that when player $i$ faces player $j$, he wins with probability $\frac{\operatorname{rk}(i)}{\operatorname{rk}(i)+\operatorname{rk}(j)}$. When a player loses a game, he gets knocked out of the tournament, thus the tournament finishes in $k$ rounds.

You are requested to arrange the players into a knockout tournament starting line-up (i.e. on the leaves of a complete binary tree of height $k$) in the way that maximizes the probability that player $1$ wins the tournament.

The official greedy solution, presented without any trace of proof, is the following:

- Sort the players $1, r_2, r_3, \dots r_{2^k}$, where $r_2, \dots r_{2^k}$ are the players $2 \dots 2^k$ sorted in ascending order of their rank.
- Arrange players $1, \dots, 2^{k-1}$ in the left-subtree and $2^{k-1} + 1, \dots 2^k$ in the right subtree and recurse.
- For each node $v$ of the tree compute (bottom-up using dynamic programming) the probability vector $P_v$ such that $P_v[x]$ is the probability of player $x$ winning the sub-tournament rooted at $v$.

This algorithm runs in $\mathcal{O}(n^2 \log n)$.

**How to prove that the algorithm is also correct?**

The original problem is from [ICPC NWERC 2017](https://people.bath.ac.uk/masjhd/NWERC/news/nwerc2017problems.pdf) (problem K). Here we posted a simplified version.

Comment: Could you provide an example of resolution ? You mentioned a greedy algorithm, and then dynamic programming, which is different

Comment: Example: rk = [9, 2, 3, 1] that is player 1 has rank 9. Then the tournament tree in balanced parentheses notation is ((9, 1), (2, 3)). This tree is found via sorting (greedy part). Then we evaluate the probability of player 1 wining employing a bottom-up DP.

Comment: Thank you. More clear now. It is clear that this Greedy algorithm (not sure Greedy is best term) is quite efficient, as we minimize the number of high ranked players to meet, and maximize the probabilty of the most ranked players to be eliminated. However, a formal proof does not seem so easy to find

Comment: This question is cross-posted on CS stackexchange. https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/119496/greedy-algorithm-on-knockout-tournaments-proof-of-correctness